# developing a node module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I was developing my own node module to put it on the npm website. This node module has some interactions with a database. I need to receive three values form the user (dbName, server, port) and set them in my module so that I can connect to the database. The first thing that came to my mind was this:
asking the user to open the config file and change the code (assign the values to the three variables):

```
var dbConf = {
    server: '',
    port: 0,
    dbName: ''
};
```

But I think this approach is totally wrong. I tried to create a function and ask the user to first call that function with the three parameters(dbName, server, port) and that function does the work for me. Then the user first require my module, then call the function and finally make use of the module:

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
myModule.config('TestDB', 'localhost', 27017);
myModule.someMethod()...
```

But I don't know how to write my index.js file to do this job! I wrote something like this: (index.js)

```
var config = function(dbName, server, port ) {
    var dbConf = {
        server: '',
        port: 0,
        dbName: ''
    };
    dbConf.server  = server;
    dbConf.port = port;
    dbConf.dbName = dbName ;
    return 'mongodb://' + dbConf.server + ':' + dbConf.port + '/' + 
    dbConf.dbName;
}

//connect to mongoDB local server
mongoose.connect(config);

module.exports = {
    config: config,
    mongoose: mongoose
};
```

But it didn't work. How can I do this job?

update:
index.js:

```
function gridFS(dbName, server, port) {
    var dbUrl = 'mongodb://' + server + ':' + port + '/' + dbName;
    this.mongoose = mongoose.connect(dbUrl);
    this.db = mongoose.connection;
    this.gfs = gridfsLockingStream(this.mongoose.connection.db, 
    this.mongoose.mongo);


    //if the connection goes through
    this.db.on('open', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("connected correctly to the server");
    });


    this.db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

}
gridFS.prototype.putFile = function putFile(...) {};
gridFS.prototype.getFileById = function getFileById(id, callback) {
    this.putFile(); //here is the problem
}
module.exports = gridFS;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your module.js file

```
let alertMethod = (message) => {
    console.log(message);
}

let myModule = (database, server, port) => {

    return {
        alert: alertMethod
    }
}

module.exports = myModule;
```

app.js file

```
let myModule = require('./module');

const _module = myModule('database', 'server', 'port');

_module.alert('YO!');
```

Comment: but how can I export my methods ?

Comment: Ok. I have updated my answer with more detailed information. There are plenty of module patterns and this is the one of them. You can check other patterns with simple google search.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with this `myModule.someMethod` of yours. Its easier if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

Despite that, your code has some easy to spot problems:

First of all, `mongoose.connect` expects a `String` parameter, as you can see [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html), but you are passing a `function` instead. Your `config` returns a `String`, yes, but its a `function` (you would need to call it in order to get a `String`).

That brings us to the second problem, when you call `mongoose.connect` like you did, it will be called as soon as you first import the module, before you are able to  call `myModule.config` and pass your parameters to create a connection string.

---

An example of how you could do it is organizing your module like this:

```
var config = function(dbName, server, port ) {
    this.connectionString = 'mongodb://' + server + ':' + port + '/' + dbName;
}

var connect = function() {
    mongoose.connect(this.connectionString);
}

module.exports = {
    config: config,
    connect: connect
}
```

Then you would use it like this

```
var myModule = require('./index.js')
myModule.config('TestDB', 'localhost', 27017);
myModule.connect();
```

This example should also give you an idea of how your other methods (like `myModule.someMethod`) will look like.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a serious problem. My code is a little bit complex. I'm using async, gridfs-stream too. And my methods are used in each other as well. Unfortunately when I use this.someMethod within my other methods, I get this error: TypeError: gridFS.somemthod is not a function. I know it's very unclear for you. Generally, how can I use methods in other methods without having this problem? (using **this** causes problems)

Comment: I updated the question and added some code. The code is quite a similar version of my real code. I want to use a function inside another and finally export all my functions.

Comment: @KasraGH In your 'updated' `index.js` you are using prototypes incorrectly. As explaining it is a more complicated topic (at least to explain in a comment), i'm going to give you an alternative. Create all your methos (`gridFS`, `putFile`...) and export them like i did in my example (creating them as variables and exporting all of them inside an object). This way you will be able to call them inside each other using `this`.

Comment: @KasraGH Actually... You are using prototypes correctly, my bad. To get this error, you must be using it incorrectly when you import. Try importing like `var gridFS = require('./index.js')` then creating your `myModule` variable like `var myModule = new gridFS('TestDB', 'localhost', 27017)`

Comment: Thank you. My problem was solved. I need to refactor the code. I shouldn't have asked the user to provide me with server, port, etc. Instead, I only need the mongoose. can you help me with this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428674/passing-mongoose-as-an-argument-to-a-function