# passing mongoose as an argument to a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I'm developing a node module. I need to pass the **mongoose** to my module to get three things (*mongoose.connection*, *mongoose.connection.db*, *mongoose.mongo*) out of it.

**index.js** (myModule - the module I developed)

```
function myModule(mongoose) {
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    var gfs = gridfsLockingStream(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
    this.someFunction = function() {//some code here}
}
module.exports = myModule;
```

**db.js** (A user must use myModule like this)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var myModule = require('myModule');

var dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/gfsTestDB';
mongoose.connect(dbUrl);

var readyObj = new myModule(mongoose);
module.exports = readyObj; // so that the user can use this everywhere
```

Then the user can use **readyObj** to do his/her work.
My problem is that only **mongoose.connection** is available in **myModule** function and I get this error(gridfsLockingStreamn cause the error):

> Error: missing db argument
>
> new Grid(db, mongo)

I'm using :

```
"mongodb": "3.0.4",

"mongoose": "4.11.6",

"gridfs-locking-stream": "1.1.1",

"gridfs-stream": "1.1.1",
```

One solution (idea from @GrégoryNEUT) (but I think it's not the correct way):

**index.js**  no changes

**db.js** using **promise** and **mongoose event handler**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var myModule = require('myModule');

var dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/gfsTestDB';
mongoose.connect(dbUrl);


module.exports = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
        var readyObj = new myModule(mongoose);
        resolve(readyObj);
    });
});
```

**photoRouter.js** (one of the user's files - the user want to use **readyObj**)

```
var readyObj = require('./db').then(function (readyObj) {
    // then the user uses readyObj
}
```

Can the code be improved?

Comment: I tried your code and it ran fine on my system without any errors.

Comment: @ViKiG Are you using the same version of the modules ?

Comment: Except for the mongoose (4.9.x) everything else is same. I installed your version of `mongoose`, still same result. There is probably something missing in your question. Post more code.

Comment: Very strange! But I've tested it hundreds of time. Are you sure you're connected to your database ? (use db.on('open' , function(){})

Comment: I think @KasraGH you've pointed it out. `.connect()` is asynchronous. You should wait the connection to be opened before to reach `mongoose.connection.*`

Comment: @KasraGH I think Gregory is right. My `mongoose` is connected when I am running your `myModule` code.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT  Should I use promises, async module or something like those to overcome this issue? How can I know if the connection is established?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of [mongoose connect](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

---

You can use of Promises.

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var myModule = require('myModule');

    var dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/gfsTestDB';

    mongoose.connect(dbUrl)
      .then(
        // The connection is ready to use!
        () => {
          var readyObj = new myModule(mongoose);

          // ...
        },

        // Handle the connection error
        (err) => {
          // ...
        },
      );
```

---

You can use of Callbacks

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var myModule = require('myModule');

    var dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/gfsTestDB';

    mongoose.connect(dbUrl, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        // Handle the error

        // ...

        return;
      }

      // We get successfully connected to the database

      var readyObj = new myModule(mongoose);

      // ...
    });
```

Comment: Perfect, but one more thing. I want to export the **readObj** like: _module.exports = readyObj_ . How can I do this? readyObj is now a local variable and is not accessible outside the mongoose success callback function.